# Android canvas hidden shape

Tags: android, canvas

I am making a small app that requires drawing some rectangle and using its `contains()` method. My problem is to draw a hidden rectangle. I'm trying to use Paint's `setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE),` then `setStrokeWidth(0)`. But the stroke is still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your paint color to transparent color. try the below

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(0xFF);

            OR

    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
```